# Centos option deletion possible

Tags: linux, unix, centos

In my boot options of my installed CentOS on VBox, I have the followings that really mess me up to figure out how to eliminate those that doesn't work anymore, e.g the first one which is reported as unavailability of kernel root to boot. I can only choose the last one to boot the system.

```
> CentOS(2.6.32-200.17.1.e16.x86_64)
> CentOS(2.6.32-200.17.1.e16.x86_64.debug)
> CentOS(2.6.32-200.4.2.e16.x86_64.debug)
> CentOS(2.6.32-200.4.2.e16.x86_64) 
> CentOS(2.6.32-200.4.1.e16.x86_64)
> CentOS(2.6.32-200.e16.x86_64)
```

Where are these stored once I boot the system with the last option ? What if I would like to delete (completely) one of them ? I don't know what the xxx.debug's are there for ?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

On most distros today the boot manager is GRUB. The configuration of boot menu is usually stored in `/boot/grub` in a file called `menu.lst` or `grub.cfg` depending on GRUB version and distro. In that file, you can comment out sets of lines corresponding to the OS you don't want in the menu - syntax should be pretty intuitive.

On some distros the file is generated by a set of scripts, in this case a comment at the top say you shouldn't edit that file directly. For example in Debian, the scripts which generate the configuration reside in `/etc/grub.d/` and they do all sorts of auto-probing for available OS's. In this case one needs to either modify the script or to remove the OS images which are automatically appended to the menu. The exact way to do this cleanly may vary depending on your setup - perhaps some of these boot images can be removed using a package manager which would be more elegant than just removing files manually.

Either way, be careful, since removing the wrong file related to booting may make it impossible to boot your OS or even to start GRUB at all if you're extremely unlucky.